# error to pass value in query Django

Tags: python, django

Hi everyone I have problem with this query in Django

```
  projects_name = str(kwargs['project_name']).split(',')
  status = str(kwargs['status'])
  list_project = tuple(projects_name)
     opc_status = {'jobs_running':'running', 'jobs_pending':'pending', 'cpus_used':'cpu'}
      if status in opc_status.values():
        key = list(opc_status.keys())[list(opc_status.values()).index(status)] + ', entry_dt' 
      else:
        key='*' 

      db = MySQLdb.connect(host='..', port=, user='..', passwd='..', db='..')
      try:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT %s FROM proj_cpus WHERE project in %s', key, list_project])
```

the first params of the query must be `*` or something like `jobs_pending, entry_dt`

but query return this error

```
tuple index out of range
```

Any idea about how to create the query correctly?

Comment: Stab the dark: `cursor.execute('SELECT %s FROM proj_cpus WHERE project in %s', key, list_project])` has stray `]` but maybe try `cursor.execute('SELECT %s FROM proj_cpus WHERE project in %s', (key, list_project))`

Comment: thanks @roganjosh if I do that I have problem with  `list_project` params, this params can be one or more name

Comment: In the case of only 1 item though, does it work? That would at least inform on the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
# Build a comma-separated string of all items in list_project
data_list = ', '.join([item for item in list_project])

query = 'SELECT %s FROM proj_cpus WHERE project in (%s)'

# Supply the parameters in the form of a tuple
cursor.execute(query, (key, data_list))
```

`cursor.fetchall()` will always return data in tuples like you have observed in comments, it is not because there is an issue with the query. To convert to json you could do something like the following (`row_counter` is just a placeholder to make sure that there is a unique key for every entry).

```
import json

key = '*'
data_list = ', '.join([item for item in list_project])

query = 'SELECT %s FROM proj_cpus WHERE project in (%s)'
cursor.execute(query, (key, data_list))
all_rows = cursor.fetchall()
row_headings = [header[0] for header in cursor.description]

row_counter = 0
all_rows_container = {}

for item in all_rows:
    item_dict = {row_headings[x]: item[x] for x in range(len(row_headings))}
    all_rows_container[row_counter] = item_dict
    row_counter += 1

json_data = json.dumps(all_rows_container)
print json_data
```

NOTE: the above may throw `IndexError` if the query is not with `key = '*'` because I think `row_headings` will contain all of the schema for the table, even for values that you did not select in the query. However, it should be sufficient to demonstrate the approach and you can tailor it in the event that you pick specific columns only.

Comment: Hi @roganjosh   I try you code, the code don't fault, but return something like this `('*',), ('*',), ('*',)` when i print    `all_rows = cursor.fetchall()
    print all_rows` and when data_list has more than one return `()`

Comment: thanks so much for your interest,  I never do a Insert in the database, the only thing that I want is read data, I know if I use `*` I get all the data but I thing is better only get the data that I need. My table has 6 columns, and in this case I only need 2 of then, this is a reason that I try to pass the name of the column in a query

Comment: @Stone ok, I understand but it's impossible for me to help you. Your code is set up for you to supply the value of `key` so you need to configure it to only get the columns that you want. Since I can't see the schema I'm not sure what anyone could do to help.

Comment: Thanks @roganjosh I am very new with Python and Django so I don't know If this way that I try is the best to do this, basically I have a database (in server, anywhere), in my local I create like a "API".I create a URL like this  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cpuProjects/name_project/category` where I pass the name of project and the category is the column in the database, this URL return in JSON the info of the database.

Comment: I don't create any model, I don't save this info I only want to show it in my view. I know that exist plugins Django rest Framework, but I don't want to use it. So the second params `status = str(kwargs['status'])` is the name of column that I want to insert in a query.